# How to combine Observable and Subject into combineLatest?

Tags: angular

I am new to combineLatest, but i am trying to combine an array which has :

```
0: Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}
1: Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}
2: Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}
3: Subject {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
4: Subject {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
5: Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}
6: Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}
```

But for some reason the

```
combineLatest(validations).subscribe(result => {console.log("it works"});
```

Doesn't fired up. I am new to this function and there is no error messages which makes it impossible for me to understand what is wrong.
if i remove the items 3-4 it fires. But i need them.
Please some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CombineLatest subscription works if every `Observable` inside has at least one value. Seems when you subscribe, some of your `validations` don't have value.

You can add start value to it, just add `.pipe(startsWith(null))` to each Observable/Subject.

Another way you can use `merge(validations)` instead if it's convenient.